# Spec of Microsoft Band

Tags: specifications, microsoft-band

I would like to the detail sensors specifications of Microsoft Band, especially about IMU sensors (accelometer, gyro... and so on) as below.

- Update rate (data trnasfer rate)
- Accuracy
- Angular Resolution

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can found some of these informations in the Microsoft Band SDK documentation on page 3 and 4:
http://developer.microsoftband.com/Content/docs/Microsoft%20Band%20SDK.pdf